# Adding an end parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameters

I've got some issues adding an `"end"` parameter to a function that searches for a specific letter in a string.

This is my code so far:

```
def find(str, ch, start=0): 
  index = start
  while index < len(str):
if str[index] == ch: 
  return index 
index = index + 1 
return -1
```

I know that I cannot use `len()` as a parameter because it is defined during the `def` process and not when I call on the find function. So it cannot be useful because the length of the string is not established during the `def`.

Thank you very much for your answers/answer.

Comment: I just tested your function and it works fine? Just don't use `str` as a variable name, but otherwise I don't see a problem. Also, fix the  indentation of your code.

Comment: Yes it works, but the exercise is to add an "end" function to the code, that's what I can't seem to be able to do.

Comment: Is the issue how to make the `end` value optional without being able to do something like `end=len(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `end` parameter like this:

```
def find(string, ch, start, end): 
    index = start
    while index <= end:            #check if it reaches the 'end' parameter
        if string[index] == ch: 
            return index 
        index = index + 1
        if index > len(string):
            break                  #break if the index is greater than len(string)
    return -1
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> find('testing123','1',0,9)
7
```

Comment: You can't place parameters with default values before parameters that don't have them.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, edited. As you can see from my demo I passed in a variable for `start`, but I forgot to update the function lol